# Which is the correct sentence? especially when using did

Tags: past-tense

Assume person 1 meets person 2. Now person 1 asks person 2 whether you saw me yesterday night around the corner of the street. What I should say in reply.

> I did see you.

or

> I did saw you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "I did see you" or "I saw you." The sentence "I did saw you" is wrong.